# refresh position using xslt for multiple elements with same name

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

The source xml document:

```
<item>
 <p languageCode="en">en</p>
 <p languageCode="fr">fr</p>
 <c languageCode="de">de</c>
 <c languageCode="nl">nl</c>
</item>
```

The needed result of the transformation must be this xml document:

```
<item>
 <p pos="1">en</p>
 <p pos="2">fr</p>
 <c pos="1">de</c>
 <c pos="2">nl</c>
</item>
```

using xslt is it possible achieve it?

Comment: Please explain the **logic** by which the `pos` values are determined.

Comment: once the element name changes the pos value is reset to 1 again. @michael.hor257k

Comment: I have rolled your question back to what it was when I answered it. I suggest you post a new question with your significantly different scenario ( and make sure to explain the rules, instead of expecting us to deduce them from the example.

Answer (score 2):

In XSLT 2.0 you can do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/item">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="name()"> 
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/> 
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p | c">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="pos" select="position()"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: i have edited the question again now its more complex structure which i am unable to crack

Comment: @divya Sorry, we're not doing this.

Comment: is it not possible in xslt 2.0 ?

Comment: I believe it is, but I am not willing to go into it here. Post a new question.

Comment: No need to post a new question -- my answer is what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

**XSLT 1.0:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
   <item><xsl:apply-templates/></item>
 </xsl:template>


     <xsl:template match="/*/*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:attribute name="pos">
           <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::*[name()=name(current())])+1"/>
         </xsl:attribute>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
       </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**XSLT 2.0**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
   <item><xsl:apply-templates/></item>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*/*">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:attribute name="pos" 
                    select="count(preceding-sibling::*[name()=name(current())])+1"/>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Another XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:key name="kByName" match="/*/*" use="name()"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
   <item><xsl:apply-templates/></item>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*/*">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:attribute name="pos" 
                  select="index-of(key('kByName', name())/generate-id(), generate-id())"/>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<item>
    <p languageCode="en">en</p>
    <p languageCode="fr">fr</p>
    <c languageCode="de">de</c>
    <c languageCode="nl">nl</c>
</item>
```

**All three** solutions produce the wanted, correct result:

```
<item>
   <p pos="1">en</p>
   <p pos="2">fr</p>
   <c pos="1">de</c>
   <c pos="2">nl</c>
</item>
```

**Do note**:

All these solutions are *generic* -- they don't depend on the names, number, number of names or order of elements.

For example, when applied on the following XML document:

```
<item>
    <p languageCode="en">en</p>
    <p languageCode="fr">fr</p>
    <c languageCode="de">de</c>
    <c languageCode="nl">nl</c>
    <d languageCode="es">es</d>
    <d languageCode="bg">bg</d>
    <d languageCode="pl">pl</d>
</item>
```

**all three solutions produce the wanted, correct result**:

```
<item>
   <p pos="1">en</p>
   <p pos="2">fr</p>
   <c pos="1">de</c>
   <c pos="2">nl</c>
   <d pos="1">es</d>
   <d pos="2">bg</d>
   <d pos="3">pl</d>
</item>
```